# Licensing for undefined user count

Tags: licensing

I have a potential client who needs a questionnaire converted into electronic format. I thought SharePoint could do the trick. Problem is, the organization only has about 7 users but the form would be filled out by around 250 years per year. What would be the best pricing model for something like that? I don't like the idea of charging them per user when those people only go to the site once to complete the questionnaire and don't really interact with SharePoint after that.

Comment: For a one off, try SurveyMonkey.com. Sharepoint is overkill for just a survey,

Comment: It's a long as questionnaire. Survey money won't do. Plus people need to go back to it and update results for each patient etcetc

Comment: You said "people only go to the site once to complete the questionnaire". A Google Spreadsheet then?

Comment: A patient would go I'm once and fill out their portion. Then their physician will update fields through the study which lasts a year.  For example blood pressure changes, etc etc. I'll look into Google spreadsheet, if the security is adequate it might do.